# How do you say "Clean" as in "clean a city"

Tags: vocabulary

How would one say "clean" as in "Clean a city" 
For example, in english we would say. 
"Once a month everyone in Rwanda leaves their house to clean the city"

Could I say 
"打扫城市“ ”把城市弄干净”？ Or is there  a better way of doing this?

Comment: Do you mean clean the city as in rid it of corruption?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use 清洁城市 or 清潔城市.  打扫 also means clean but it is usually used when cleaning (actually sweeping) happens in a smaller area (i.e. cleaning your place / your room etc)

Comment: Speaking of size, I would also not use the object marker 把 in conjunction with 城市 or anything that is considerably larger than what a hand can grasp. I would use constructs such as 让 or 将 instead.

Comment: So  I couldn't say  把飞机弄干净？ does 把 really imply size？

Comment: What about a road? Could I say 他们去打扫他们的路

Comment: @Stephen Since 打扫 is the action of sweeping, you can apply it - i.e. you will sweep the road but usually you don't sweep an airplane.

Answer (score 1):

I think your best bet is: **清洁** it's usually used as an adjective like:

> clean; sanitary
>
> 她的房间整齐清洁。
>
> ²Tā de fángjiān zhěngqí qīngjié.
>
> Her room is tidy and clean. -*ABC*

But! It's also used frequently as a verb!

In china at the moment a lot of cities even have 清洁城市活动 or 清洁城市日.

Comment: Could I say that the individuals than go 清洁？ As in 
“所有的卢旺达人回去清洁”

Comment: Sure...but 回去清洁 what?

Comment: 会去清洁   I meant to use 会

Comment: Na I meant they will clean *what*? What will they clean?